# How to access a library's function in .onAttach()?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm writing an R package and I need it run a short bit of code before the user dives in.  Specifically, this is my `.onAttach()`:

```
#' @importFrom httr GET
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    url <- "http://news.bbc.co.uk"
    sink <- GET(url)
}
```

`httr` is listed under the Imports part of my DESCRIPTION file.

My problem is that when I run `R CMD check` I get the following error:

```
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'scholar', details:
  call: default_ua()
  error: could not find function "packageVersion"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'scholar'
```

Since `packageVersion()` is in `utils`, which I'm guessing isn't available at this stage in the package loading process, I can "solve" this by adding `library(utils)` in the first line of `.onAttach()` but then I get this NOTE:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
'library' or 'require' call to 'utils' in package code.
  Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.
  See section 'Suggested packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

I've tried replacing the library call with `requireNamespace("utils")` but that's not helping either.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to fix this; my own searches aren't turning up anything useful.

Comment: I don't understand how the `onAttach` code relates to the error regarding `packageVersion`. Where does `scholar` come in? Do you have a github repository for the package?

Comment: Per `?.onAttach`, *There should be no calls to 'library' nor 'require' in these hooks.* Have you tried `sink <- httr::GET(url)`?

Comment: `scholar` is the name of the package I'm working on; it's on Github but this is a new feature and I haven't pushed the code yet.  I did try `httr::GET` but no dice.  Also I saw the "no calls" thing in the manual and elsewhere; maybe `onAttach` is the wrong place to try and do this?  It must be possible to run some library-based code automatically when loading another package.

Comment: Do you have a non-standard path for your R packages? (`system.file(package='httr')` and similarly with `'utils'`) Should have asked if you tried `utils::packageVersion()`, but I assume that `utils` would be available ootb.

Comment: I'm currently working around this problem by delaying the call until the user calls one of the public functions.  I'd still like to know if there's a way to do this when loading the package though.

Comment: I would also try `if(requireNamespace("utils")) getFromNamespace(...)`